# Error with middleware and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have this :

```
app.use(session({secret: 'JKSBDFJKQS444SQ4DQSND'}));
```

But when I run my app file I got this **error :**

> Error: Most middleware is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately.

How to fix ?

Comment: You might want to look at the (admittedly abbreviated) [3 to 4 migration guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x)

Answer (score 0):

From the express 4.x Docs "As of 4.x, Express no longer depends on Connect. All of Express' previously included middleware are now in separate repos. Please view the list of middleware. The only included middleware is now express.static()." See [here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#middleware) for the details.

Comment: Yep but the doc's examples still on the old version so how ?

https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: This was previously included in ['connect'](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) which was bundled with express. You now need to add connect to your app and require it like you did express.`app.use(connect.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', key: 'sid', cookie: { secure: true }}))`